# Getting my Post models' Comments to load and render

Tags: ember.js, model, relationships

I'm endeavouring to build a blog of sorts in Ember. One in which I can log in (not there yet), make posts, and then leave comments and add posts to favourites. Right now, I can't seem to get my posts' comments to load at all — I assumed that once I had the relationships defined, they'd load themselves and I could access them at any point.

Here's my JSBin of the work in progress:

http://jsbin.com/nog/3/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `post: ['2']` to `post: '2'` (since it's a `belongsTo` relationship it expects a value not an array):

```
App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    post: DS.belongsTo('post', { async: true }),
    date_posted: DS.attr('date'),
    author: DS.attr('string'),
    message: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Comment.FIXTURES = [{
    id: '1',
    post: '2',
    date_posted: new Date(),
    author: 'Aaron',
    message: 'Psyched for the third.'
}];
```

See http://jsbin.com/daqonone/1/